# 2 DIVs next to eachother without Float

Tags: css

DIV#1's content is an image and the content of DIV#2 is a input text field.

```
#1 {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

#2 {
  height: 48px;
}
```

I don't want to use floats because then the image of #1 breaks layout upon zooming the page.
I tried it with a table but then I can't set margins and padding to them.
Also tried display: inline-block but then I can also not use padding/margin.

I use % sizing on my entire page with the exception of padding so it's all works with zoom and different resolutions.

Comment: Usually if you want inline you would use spans

Comment: Div is a block level element.  Use display:inline to achieve what you are doing by keeping Div widths in mind.

Comment: I tried this with two spans but the image appears above the input field that I have and margin-top does not work but margin-left does...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XWsS8/1/)

Make sure that container they are in has equivalent or more width than DIV's(combined) and use this CSS:

```
#1, #2 { display: inline-block }
```

Also you can't use numbers as ID's in `<HTML5`, so I have used a, b instead 1,2 in demo.

You should be able to use padding/margin with this example as long as container width is enough as shown in demo.

Comment: Note: in HTML5, which your fiddle is rendered in, IDs *can* start with a number. Pretty much any character that is not empty or a space can be used now, for classes *and* IDs.

Comment: I know that this is old, but we have the same issue but with inline-block, you seemingly cannot vertical-align:middle.  Any help would be appreciated!!